# dropdown list expands under a View element

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I am using this dropdown picker library from `import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';` which kinda doesnt expand properly when inside View that has certain styles.

Here is some code:

```
<View style={styles.cellBox}>
                            <DropDownPicker
                                items={[
                                    { label: '5', value: 5 },
                                    { label: '10', value: 10 },
                                    { label: '20`', value: 20 },
                                    { label: '45`', value: 45 },
                                    { label: '57`', value: 57 },
                                ]}
                                itemStyle={{
                                    justifyContent: 'flex-start'
                                }}
                                dropDownStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#fafafa' }}
                                onChangeItem={item => buyOfferStore.setBatchQuantityInTons(item.value)}
                            />
</View>
```

Style has cellbox property that looks like:

```
 cellBox: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "space-between",
        alignItems: "center",
        borderTopWidth: 1,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderColor: theme.colors.lightSilver,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        padding: 10,
        minHeight: 55,
        marginTop: -1,
    },
```

Output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HW0UC.png)

If I remove style from View element works fine. No idea why is it behaving so, I cannot remove the style from View element as I need to style the View element to look in certain way!

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is aproblem with the View element, you see you have a style of cellbox and you probabaly used it for the cell below as well and they have the same zIndex level. So any overlays won't be shown. You could try to create a special class for DropDownPicker View and give it an extra style of   zIndex: 2,

Such as:

View style={styles.cellBox1}>
<DropDownPicker
...

cellBox1: {
...
zIndex: 2,
},

Comment: I have already tried what you suggested, it didnt work.

Comment: Also it seems that this dropdown doewnt like its parent View to have background color